# utf-8 string from python to java android in AWS

Tags: android, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have the following problem:

I sent this string over AWS SQS service (with no quotes) using python:

"Talhão"

When I looked at the web interface of SQS, I found the following string (also with no quotes):

"VGFsaMOjbw=="

Which also is the same string returned in the android java API of SQS. How do I convert "VGFsaMOjbw==" back to "Talhão"?
Already tried this code, but didn't worked:

```
String debug = new String(m.getBody().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Update: Found out how to do it using java. Must be converted to base64.

```
String debug = m.getBody();
Log.d("AWSQS", debug);

byte[] tmp2 = Base64.decode(debug, Base64.DEFAULT); 
String val2 = new String(tmp2, "UTF-8");
Log.d("AWSQS", val2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you would do:

```
binascii.a2b_base64(s).decode('utf-8')
```

If you're looking for the Java equivalent to that, then you need to put a "Java" tag instead of a "Python" tag in your question :-)

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't put the Java tag because I inserted the android tag. Also found out how to do it on java.